# Identity involving the Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

I am trying to understand an identity involving the Hadamard product of two matrices $A_1, A_2$ over the complex numbers of dimension $n$.

Define

$$S = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (e_i) \otimes(e_i)^t \otimes (e_1) \otimes (e_i)^t$$

which in Dirac notation is

$$S = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} |i \rangle \langle i| \otimes |0^n \rangle \langle i|$$

and $e_i$ is the standard row vector with a $1$ in the $i$th index, and $0$ elsewhere.

A paper I am reading states without proof that

$$S(A_1 \otimes A_2)S^{\dagger} = (A_1 \circ A_2) \otimes |0^n \rangle \langle 0^n| = (A_1 \circ A_2) (e_1) \otimes (e_1)^t$$

where the second equality uses Dirac notation and where $A_1 \circ A_2$ is the Hadamard product of two matrices. Any insights as to how this equation is obtained much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a computation.

We have
$$
S^\dagger=\sum_i e_i\otimes e_i^t\otimes e_i\otimes e_1^t
$$
So
$$
(A_1\otimes A_2)S^\dagger = \sum_i A_1e_i\otimes e_i^t\otimes A_2 e_i\otimes e_1^t
$$
and
\begin{align*}
S(A_1\otimes A_2)S^\dagger 
&= \left(\sum_j e_j\otimes e_j^t\otimes e_1\otimes e_j^t\right)\left(\sum_i A_1e_i\otimes e_i^t\otimes A_2 e_i\otimes e_1^t\right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j}\left( e_j\otimes e_j^t\otimes e_1\otimes e_j^t\right)\left( A_1e_i\otimes e_i^t\otimes A_2 e_i\otimes e_1^t\right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j}\left( (e_j\otimes e_j^t)(A_1e_i\otimes e_i^t)\otimes (e_1\otimes e_j^t)(A_2 e_i\otimes e_1^t)\right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j}\left( (e_j^t A_1 e_i)(e_j\otimes  e_i^t)\otimes (e_j^t A_2 e_i)(e_1 \otimes e_1^t)\right)\\
&= \sum_{i,j} (e_j^t A_1 e_i)(e_j^t A_2 e_i)\left((e_j\otimes  e_i^t)\otimes (e_1 \otimes e_1^t)\right)\\
&= \left(\sum_{i,j} (e_j^t (A_1\circ A_2) e_i)(e_j\otimes  e_i^t)\right)\otimes (e_1 \otimes e_1^t)\\
&= (A_1\circ A_2) \otimes (e_1 \otimes e_1^t)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: $S^{\dagger} = S$?

Comment: @IntegrateThis no, $(\lvert a\rangle\otimes\langle b\rvert\otimes\langle c\vert\otimes\lvert d\rangle)^\dagger = \lvert b\rangle\otimes\langle a\rvert\otimes\langle d\vert\otimes\lvert c\rangle$, and note my $S^\dagger$ ends in $e_i\otimes e_1^t$ not $e_1\otimes e_i^t$.